# Maintaining Conversation Context in Django API View with OpenAI GPT for Chat Application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am building a chat application using Django that integrates with OpenAI's GPT to generate responses based on the conversation history. I've set up an APIView in Django to handle the chat interactions but am struggling with maintaining and sending the previous conversation context to the OpenAI API for generating contextually relevant responses.

Current Implementation:

Here's the simplified version of my ChatGptApiView:

```
class ChatGptApiView(APIView):
    # permission_classes =[IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'gpt/gpt.html')
    
    def post(self, request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.data
            conversation_history = []
            user_prompt = data.get('user_prompt')
            # assistant_prompt = data.get('assistant_prompt')
            profile_id = data.get('profile_id')
            user_id = request.user.id
            regenerate = data.get('regenerate', False) 
            try:
                profile_data = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
            except Profile.DoesNotExist:
                return error_response(error_message="Profile not found", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            
            user_input = None

            if user_prompt is not None:
                user_input = {"role": "user", "content": user_prompt}
                conversation_history.append(user_input)
                save_chat_to_mongodb(profile_data, user_input, user_id, regenerate)

            recent_chats = get_recent_chats(int(profile_id))
            # print("recent_chats",recent_chats,"::::")
            
            old_chats = recent_chats.get('chat', []) if 'chat' in recent_chats else []
            old_chats = [{k: v for k, v in item.items() if k != 'created_at'} for item in old_chats]
            if len(old_chats) > 0:
                conversation_history.extend(old_chats)

            print(conversation_history, "================================================================")
            # Define a generator function to stream the response
            def generate_response(context, message, profile_name):
                print(conversation_history,"::::::::")
                
                if profile_name is not None:

                    context.append({
                        'role': 'user',
                        'content':f"You will follow the current conversation and previous conversation and respond to the queries asked by the 'user's content. You will act as the assistant.\nUser input: {message}"
                    })
                else:
                    context.append({
                        'role': 'user',
                        'content': f"Past data are past conversations with ChatGPT, which offer replies exclusively in new lines and only on previous chat outcomes.\nUser input: {message}"
                    })
                try:
                    # Construct the conversation history with message objects
                    conversation = [{"role": msg["role"], "content": msg["content"]} for msg in context]

                    total_tokens = sum(count_tokens(msg["content"]) for msg in conversation)
                    print(total_tokens,":>>>>>")
                    # Check if the total tokens exceed the limit
                    if total_tokens > 4096:
                        return {"error": "Total tokens in the conversation exceed the limit (4096 tokens)"}


                    # Call the OpenAI API with streaming
                    stream = openai.chat.completions.create(
                        model="gpt-4",
                        messages=conversation,
                        # frequency_penalty=0.0,
                        temperature=1,
                        max_tokens=1000,
                        stop=None,
                        stream=True
                    )
                    assistant_response = ""
                    for chunk in stream:
                        if chunk.choices[0].delta.content is not None:
                            response_text = chunk.choices[0].delta.content

                            assistant_response += str(response_text)
                            
                        yield response_text 
                    assistant_content = None
                    if assistant_response:
                        if isinstance(assistant_response, str):
                            assistant_content = assistant_response
                        elif isinstance(assistant_response, dict):
                            assistant_content = assistant_response.get('content', '')
                        else:
                            assistant_content = str(assistant_response) 
                        assistant = {"role": "assistant", "content": assistant_response}
                        save_chat_to_mongodb(profile_data, assistant, user_id, regenerate)
                    conversation_history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": assistant_content})
                    print(conversation_history)


                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
                    return {"status": False, "error": "Something went wrong"}
                

                
            # Return a streaming response to the client
            return StreamingHttpResponse(generate_response(conversation_history, user_prompt, profile_id), content_type='text/event-stream')

        
        # Return a JSON error if the request method is not POST
        return Response({'error': 'Method not allowed.'}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

**Issues:**

Maintaining Context: I'm unsure how to properly maintain and structure the conversation history for each user session to ensure the OpenAI API understands the context of the conversation.
Data Structure: What's the best way to structure the data sent to OpenAI to maximize the quality of the responses?
Efficiency: How can I efficiently manage the token limit imposed by OpenAI (4096 tokens) without losing important conversation context?
Error Handling: I need advice on best practices for handling errors or exceptions in this setup, especially related to API limits or unexpected responses.
**Attempted Solutions:**

I tried appending new user inputs to a list (conversation_history) and included previous chats fetched from a database.
I considered implementing a truncation strategy for when the conversation exceeds the token limit but am unsure how to best apply this without losing crucial context.
**Questions:**

How can I effectively maintain and send conversation history in a Django APIView when integrating with OpenAI's GPT?
Is there a recommended approach for structuring conversation history to ensure contextually relevant responses from OpenAI?
Any tips on managing the conversation's token count efficiently to stay within OpenAI's limits?
I appreciate any insights or examples from those who have tackled similar issues.